# Horizontal and Vertical Center not working with iOS Safari?

Tags: css, center

This is my first website I am making for a family friend. I have a series of images on this website (the spots tabs - ie baseball, football, softball etc) with an h1 text that I wanted to be centered vertically and horizontally.  It works on my mobile and browser.  But my brother told me it ends up not centering on his iphone 6 with safari.

http://www.pennfamous.com/tp/

I am using the following css to center the h1:

```
.h1format h1 {
    color: #FFFFFF; 
    position: absolute;
    top: 40%;
    left:50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    font-size: 2em;
}
```

However, my brother told me on his iOS it ends up looking like this:

http://prntscr.com/9pdqk0

Is there a simple fix for this?  Remember I am a novice.  Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Safari you need the -webkit-prefix. And you might as well add the -ms-prefix to get support in IE9 (even if it's dying).

```
.h1format h1 {
  color: #FFFFFF; 
  position: absolute;
  top: 40%;
  left:50%;
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%,-50%); /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%,-50%); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  font-size: 2em;
}
```

Comment: thank you very much for the response.  I added that code but he tells me it is still the same.  Is there some kind of cache he would need to clear or refresh?  Can't tell if it's the code not working or if its just not updated for him

Comment: I guess it's a cache problem. Ask him to try in incognito mode. It works fine in this simulator: http://iphone4simulator.com/